# xslt copy part of xml without using xsl:copy

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I am trying to copy part (all elements that contain "a") of this xml code without using `xsl:copy`.

XML code:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="mydata.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
    <a>
        <ab x="x"><b>Test</b><a>z</a></ab>
        <z x="x"><a>z</a></z>
    </a>
```

Desired outcome:

```
<a>
    <ab x="x"><a>z</a></ab>
</a>
```

I've managed to get the desired outcome using `xsl:copy` (see below), but unsure of how to change it so it doesn't contain that. Using `xsl:element` maybe? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

using `xsl:copy`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="a | @* |ab">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="b|z"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want to copy, why is it important not to use the tool designed for copying?

Comment: what you mean by "but unsure of how to change it so it doesn't contain that."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(contains(name(), 'a'))]"/>
```

Comment: So where is the "*without using `xsl:copy`*" part?

Comment: It's still unclear why `<xsl:copy>` should not be used. *"Because the OP said so"* is usually a bad reason. This code does what `<xsl:copy>` would do, but: A) It's more complex and B) any XSLT processor that is capable of running this code supports `<xsl:copy>`. So...

Comment: @Tomalak You are right that the solution without <xsl:copy> is more complex, but this is author's requirements. May be this is a tutorial's task for students (for understanding how the xsl:copy really works, for example)...

Comment: That's what the OP should disclose at the start. There is no use in speculation. For any given task a proper solution should be used unless good reasons are presented why a proper solution is not acceptable. Just doing the OPs bidding is... not optimal.

Comment: @AlexanderDyuzhev - You are correct. I know the solution without <xsl:copy> is more complex. This was part of an activity to understand how different ways of coding can lead to the same output. Thanks for your help.